# SpringBoot 3 + Hibernate 6, How to configure version of mysql dialect

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-6.x

```
HHH90000026: MySQL8Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead
```

In SpringBoot 3 + Hibernate 6, MySQL8Dialect is deprecated in favor of MySQLDialect

the problem is that MySQLDialect requires to set constructor parameter which version to use.

So,

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect(8)
```

isn't working.

And

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

will use default version which is 5.0.

How to specify version 8 with using

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

?

Comment: I had a similar experience with OracleDialect. My solution was to remove the dialect configuration altogether and let "hibernate decide" what it wants to use. For my case with H2 or Oracle it works quite well.

Comment: without dialect - org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')

It wouldn't be problem if it would be pure hibernate app. in spring boot we need to setup spring.datasource.url